# FreeMarker: How to get TemplateDirectiveBody as String while implementing TemplateDirectiveModel?

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I am creating a custom FreeMarker directive. As part of my implementation, I want to access the Body of my custom directive inside the execute method. Is there a way to get it from either TemplateDirectiveBody body or Environment env?

Usage in template

```
<@loop>My name is ${name}</@loop>
```

Implementation

```
public class LoopDirective implements TemplateDirectiveModel{
    public LoopDirective() {
    }
    public void execute(Environment env,
      Map params, TemplateModel[] loopVars,
      TemplateDirectiveBody body)
      throws TemplateException, IOException {
        System.out.println(body);
        // I want to print "My name is ${name}"
    }
}
```

I don't want the full template string by using something like:

```
Writer w = new StringWriter();
env.getCurrentTemplate().dump(w);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the point is that you don't want `${name}` to be resolved (otherwise you could just use the `TemplateDirectiveBody` API). You aren't supposed to be able to do that. But, I think you can pull a dirty trick, by getting the positions in the source from `env.getCurrentDirectiveCallPlace()`. Now you know which part of the original source code you need to cut out, though it will include the delimiting tags, so you will need to remove those with your own program logic (a bit of simplified parsing...). As of getting the source code of the template, in theory the `Template` object should not have that. But thanks to some bad legacy, you got `Template.getSource(int, int, int, int)`. But, it will replace tabs with spaces, unless you set the `tabSize` to 1 in the `Configuration`. Another thing to know is that `Template.getSource` is somewhat slow (copies around characters in memory somewhat wastefully), plus you have to remove the delimiting tags each time. But the speed issue also can be worked around by using `DirectiveCallPlace.getOrCreateCustomData`, which lets you cache the final `String` per call place.

Comment: Thank you for response. Yes, I don't want to `${name}` to be resolved. When you say "You aren't supposed to be able to do that", any specific reason why?
Also I wonder why [getChildrenBuffer](https://github.com/apache/incubator-freemarker/blob/2.3-gae/src/main/java/freemarker/core/Environment.java#L2807) is not public here?
Template.getSource(int, int, int, int) is not going to help me. What I am trying to do with my custom directive is avoid nesting, but allow repetition. 
valid

    <@loop>${abc}</@loop> <@loop>${xyz}</@loop>

invalid 

    <@loop>${abc}<@loop>${xyz}</@loop></@loop>

Comment: Well, if you instruct the template language to substitute a value, then it's rather unusual to suppress that behavior, and is confusing to whoever reads the template (as you have altered the documented behavior). But I don't understand what you want to achieve. You could ban nesting `loop` into `loop` with checking a global variable on runtime. Why's that related to not resolving `${exp}`? AST API-s, esp. `getChildrenBuffer`, are low level implementation detail.

Comment: Again thank you for your reply. How I can ban nesting `loop` into `loop` with checking a global variable on runtime?
We are accepting templates from users, so as a security thing I want to avoid infinite loops or too many iterations. I am creating a custom loop directive `<@loop>` like `#list` where I can control maximum number of loop iterations and can also restrict nesting i.e. `<@loop><@loop></@loop><@/loop>`. But repetition should work, like `<@loop></@loop><@loop></@loop>`.

Comment: What do you exactly mean how? `Environment` has `get/setGlobalVariable` methods. You can maintain nesting depth and iteration count there (even total iteration count, so you don't have to ban nesting itself). Globals are also readable and writable from templates though. If that's a problem (or just need more complex purely Java values) use `get/setCustomState` instead.

Comment: Also note that it requires depending on some internal API-s, but another possibility is making template execution interruptable (via `Thread.interrupt()`). See https://github.com/apache/incubator-freemarker-online-tester how. You can see this in action at http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/, if you enter a long running loop.